# Infinite loop when using @RetryableTopic

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to use two @KafkaListener the first with @RetryableTopic

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class RetryableKafkaListener {

  @RetryableTopic(
      attempts = "4",
      backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
      autoCreateTopics = "false",
      topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE)
  @KafkaListener(topics = "orders")
  public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    log.info(in + " from " + topic);
    throw new RuntimeException("test");
  }

  @DltHandler
  public void dlt(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    log.info(in + " from " + topic);
  }
}
```

and the second is a simple Listener

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class BasicKafkaListener {

  @KafkaListener(topics = "another-orders")
  public void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    log.info(in + " from " + topic);
    throw new RuntimeException("another test");
  }

}
```

I raised a RunTimeException when processing Listeners on both of them.

The first "RetryableKafkaListener" is working as excepted afters 4 attemps i get the record on the DLT topic.
The second should end after 10 failures "DefaultErrorHandler". but instead i get an infinite loop. i tried to set manually a FixedBackOff , but it's not working

When i remove the first RetryableKafkaListener with the BasicKafkaListener work as excepted and it stop after 10 failures.

My question is how to get both Listeners working as excepted should i define 2 ListenerContainer ?

I pushed a project on github https://github.com/elfelli/fork-spring-kafka-non-blocking-retries-and-dlt

To reprodure just run the app and push a record on the topic "another-order"

kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic another-orders

I'm not sure if this a bug or a bad use

i'm using

```
spring_boot_version= 2.6.2
spring_dependency_management_version=1.0.11.RELEASE
spring_kafka_version=2.8.1
```

Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 0):

First - you should not specify a spring-kafka version; Spring Boot 2.6.x uses Spring for Apache Kafka 2.8.x. You should let Boot bring in the correct version. The sample pulls in 2.7.0.

It is by design - you should use a different container factory when mixing listener types.

Comment: Correction - you need to use a different container factory for each type.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2069

Comment: Thank you @Gary for your quick response, i will define two different container factory

Comment: @elfelli, we've made an enhancement to the feature and now you can share the same factory between retryable and non-retryable topics: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-lcf Thanks for bringing this up.